# TypeError: Cannot read property 'elGamal' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, cryptography, sjcl, elgamal

Im running the below code snippet and I'm getting the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'elGamal' of undefined**

```
    var sjcl = require("sjcl");
    var keys = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.publicKey(); //choose a stronger/weaker curve

    var pubkem = keys.pub.kem(); //KEM is Key Encapsulation Mechanism
    var pubkey = pubkem.key;
    var seckey = keys.sec.unkem(pubkem.tag); //tag is used to derive the secret (private) key

    var plain = "hello world!";
    var cipher = sjcl.encrypt(pubkey, plain); //defaults to AES
    var result = sjcl.decrypt(seckey, cipher);

    console.log(plain === result); //true
```

Comment: Give it a try with `require('sjcl-complete')`.

Comment: It gave me this error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined
    at Object.publicKey (/home/runner/EquatorialAlphanumericExecutable/node_modules/sjcl-complete/sjcl.js:124:62)**

Comment: Try using e.g. `var keys = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(sjcl.ecc.curves.k256);`

Comment: It worked. you made my day, thank you @Topaco.